# GAE java server fails to activate Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: google-app-engine, webserver

I'm trying to set the server for allow cross domain scripting,to access to my assets provided by appengine: "static.myapp.org"

I added this  configuration to my appengine-web.xml as explain in  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig

```
   <static-files>
      <include path="/**.txt" >
        <http-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://myapp.org" />
      </include>
    </static-files>
```

After setting this config, I received the next error when trying to upload:

```
Bad configuration: XML error validating /war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml against /opt/appengine-java-sdk-1.6.6/docs/appengine-web.xsd
  Caused by: cvc-complex-type.2.2: Element 'include' must have no element [children], and the value must be valid.
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP headers on static content were [introduced in GAE SDK 1.7.0](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkForJavaReleaseNotes). You seem to be using 1.6.6.